# Sort arraylist by number of times in arraylist and then remove duplicates

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, duplicates

Right now I have something in php that looks like this:

```
$count = array_count_values($result);
arsort($count);

foreach($count as $key => $val){
    $result[] = $key;
}
```

It will count all the items in the array and put it into a key/value pair. Which will remove the duplicates and then I tell it to sort. Then I take the key of it and store it. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing. `arsort` doesn't sort by the value in the array. It sorts by the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Java has an equivalent to the `array_count_values` function, so you will need to implement that yourself. Something like this:

```
public static <T> Map<T, Integer> countValues(List<T> values) {
    Map<T, Integer> result = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    // iterate through values, and increment its corresponding value in result
    return result;
}
```

Then use the `java.util.Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)` function to sort the array by the counts. You'll need to implement Comparator to sort by the counts.

```
public class CountComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    private Map<T, Integer> counts;

    public CountComparator(Map<T, Integer> counts) {
        this.counts = counts;
    }

    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        // assumes that the map contains all keys
        return counts.get(o1).compareTo(counts.get(o2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [`Multiset`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) from the Google Guava library to get counts. It works in a similar way to PHP's `array_count_values`.

If you want it sorted by the key, then use the [`TreeMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) implementation.

If you want it sorted on count, then use [Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst%28com.google.common.collect.Multiset%29)

Comment: If you want it sorted by count, then that blog post is [out of date](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#copyHighestCountFirst(com.google.common.collect.Multiset)).